# CSS lower specificity rules override higher specificity rules

Tags: css, css-specificity

I have this simple CSS code:

```
p.child-class {
    color: red;
}

.parent-class p {
    color: green;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="parent-class">
    <p class="child-class"></div>
</div>
```

The selector `.parent-class` is being applied instead of the higher specificity selector `p.child-class`. Why is that?
Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qMwtZ/).

**EDIT**

I understand that both have the same specificity. In that case, how can I increase the specificity of the child's class if I can't edit the parent's class code?

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/9MmcB/ You'll have to post your HTML and explain what you expect to happen.

Comment: If you switch the order of the rules it can be reproduced, so what order are these rules applied to the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selectors `.parent-class p` and `p.child-class` have exactly the same CSS specificity, both have 1 tag selector and 1 class selector. The selector that comes later in code will apply.

Comment: How would I increase the specificity of the child then? I cant touch the parent class

Comment: As a sort of "hack" (totally [valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) though), you may specify the classname twice: `p.child-class.child-class`. It won't change the selector meaning, but will increase its formal specificity.

Comment: This works great... if no one else finds a more elegant solution i'll accept your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Your both rules having different meaning

```
.parent-class p
```

this specify the rule for `p` which is inside the container having class `.parent-class`

```
p.child-class
```

this specify the rule for `p` which has the class `child-class`

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/XhGnU/)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, they have the same specificity, the the order of the rules is significant.

Adding `.parent-class` will change the specificity

```
.parent-class p.child-class {
```

and then the order won't matter.

Comment: What if I can't edit the code of the `parent-class`? How would I increase the specificity of the child then?

Comment: My answer is increasing the specificity of the css-rules that will apply to `child-class`. If you can edit the HTML then you can, of course, add a completely new class or id's.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `!important`

[When Using !important is The Right Choice](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)